# background monitoring of GPIO pin in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, gpio

I am afraid that this is a very basic questions, where I could not find the correct search terms for, so any help would be highly appreciated.

I would like constantly monitor a GPIO (24) pin of a raspberry. In the minimal example I connected it to a button and would like to show the number of presses on the dash site. I managed to do that with *dash_core_components.Interval* shown [here](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates). However, this also refreshes the page every interval. I would like like to constantly monitor the GPIO pin and only show the current count value on a site refresh.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

globalCounter = 0
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN) #connected to 3.3V Pin of the pi, separated by a button.

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H1(id="live-update-text"),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_metrics(n):
    global globalCounter
    if GPIO.input(24) == 1:
        globalCounter += 1
    return "Number of presses:  "+str(globalCounter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I guess for that I need to link the *app.layout* to a function (as in the 2. example in the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates)), but how do I still constantly monitor if a button is pressed or not?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution with threading. The GPIO is monitored in a while loop in a thread and the dash layout is linked to a function, as described in the documentation.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import threading

gC = 0
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
def thread_function():
   isButtonPressed = False #bool to avoid multi registration per press
   while True:
       global gC
       if GPIO.input(24) == 1 and not isButtonPressed:
           isButtonPressed = True
           gC += 1
       elif GPIO.input(24) == 0 and isButtonPressed:
           isButtonPressed = False

x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
x.start()


app = dash.Dash()
colors = {
    'background': '#ff0000',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}
def sever_layout():
    return  html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, children=[
        html.H1(children='Counter '+str(gC))
        ])
app.layout = sever_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: `while True:` in thread function is incorrect.

Comment: I also recommend to look into proper API for monitoring GPIO line either in the ugly RPi library, or by switching over to the standard `libgpiod`.